# Promises not resolving in the order they were called

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, promise

I am integrating a website with firebase.  I am trying to get user IDs from my users collection in the database and then pass each of the user IDs to another function that gets the experience data from another collection.   I order the users by name because i want the users sorted alphabetically on my page. The code works as I have it except that the promises do not resolve in the correct order and thus are not output alphabetically.  Please see details below:

1. First i get the users with the getUserProfiles function.
2. i confirm each user ID by printing out each index directly (users[0], users[1], users[2]).
3. I then loop through each user and console log the user ID before and after the database query.
4. Looking at the console logs, it looks like the user ids are being passed to the database query in the correct order, but the 2nd ID is resolving before the first ID.  the first ID passed to the database is 'ZKnqtLVzUqNqdzX9f8ap76LThh32'. Yet, '482uR9t2QEdCUi0Z4nq14VRVhEx1' resolves first

Why are the IDs not resolving in the order that they were passed?

```
    function getUserProfiles(){
      //get users, usernames and render profiles
        db.getUsers().then(users => {
          console.log('first index:', users[0].id);
          console.log('second index:', users[1].id);
          console.log('third index:', users[2].id);
          users.forEach(user => {
            db.getLatestExperience(user.id).then(()=>{

            })
        })  
    }

    Class {
        getLatestExperience(id, callback) {
          console.log('getLatestExperience before database request:', id);
          return this.experience.where('userID', '==', id).orderBy('start','desc').get().then(snapshot => {            
          console.log('getLatestExperience promise resolved', id);
        })        
      }

     getUsers(callback) {
       return this.users.orderBy('name').get().then(snapshot => {
            return snapshot.docs;
        })
      }
    }


    first index: ZKnqtLVzUqNqdzX9f8ap76LThh32
    second index: 482uR9t2QEdCUi0Z4nq14VRVhEx1
    third index: 7bJBqk2gQBeTIZOY5h3FikO0Yqm2
    getLatestExperience before database request: ZKnqtLVzUqNqdzX9f8ap76LThh32
    getLatestExperience before database request: 482uR9t2QEdCUi0Z4nq14VRVhEx1
    getLatestExperience before database request: 7bJBqk2gQBeTIZOY5h3FikO0Yqm2
    getLatestExperience promise resolved: 482uR9t2QEdCUi0Z4nq14VRVhEx1
    getLatestExperience promise resolved: ZKnqtLVzUqNqdzX9f8ap76LThh32
    getLatestExperience promise resolved: 7bJBqk2gQBeTIZOY5h3FikO0Yqm2
```

Comment: Promises don't resolve in the order their underlying operations were started unless some underlying system forces them that way.  Promises represent asynchronous operations that can finish in ANY order unless you specifically sequence them or specifically order the results regardless of when each one finishes.

Comment: Probably what you should be doing is using something like `Promise.all()` to know when a whole array of promises are done and to collect the results in the desired order for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the promises in an array and `reduce` them so they execute sequential:

```
const promiseArray = [promise2, promise3...]
    promiseArray.reduce(
        (prev, next) => prev.then(prevResult => next(prevResult)), promise1())
            .then(finalResult => {...})
```

`promiseArray` is an array of functions that returns a promise. You leave out the first one, as you need a starting one later.
`Array.reduce` will execute one after another.
`prev` is your previous promise you are resolving and if needed, for the next one, you can resolve it with a result and pass it over to next. 
Finally at the end you can resolve the whole reduce with one single result from the last promise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) in order to resolve when all users return. `Promise.all` have it built in to order the result array the same as the given promises

```js
function getUserProfiles() {
  //get users, usernames and render profiles
  return db.getUsers()
    .then(users => {
      console.log('first index:', users[0].id);
      console.log('second index:', users[1].id);
      console.log('third index:', users[2].id);

      const latestExperiencePerUserPromises = users
        .map((user) => db.getLatestExperience(user.id));

      return Promise.all(latestExperiencePerUserPromises);
    });
}
```